# best approach for extending ,rewriting the core classes in laravel

Tags: laravel, class, laravel-5

What is the best way to extend,rewrite the core classes in laravel. For now what i am doing is making a file in app directory making the use namespace and rewriting the method and modifying the core class is no the best practices too..i have done some core classes modification where the project would not need to upgrade.

i want to rewrite the  file vendor/laravel/illuminate/foundation/auth/ResetsPasswords.php i want to rewrite the existing method for reset()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ResetsPasswords` trait in your controller and override `reset()` method there. There is no need really for extending any class in the example you've mentioned.

Read more about traits here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php